# How to call functions in MATLAB R2007b

Tags: matlab

I used the following code which is available in the MATLAB object oriented programming book to create a class:

```
classdef BasicClass
     properties
        Value
     end
     methods
     function r = roundOff(obj)
        r = round([obj.Value],2);
     end
     function r = multiplyBy(obj,n)
        r = [obj.Value] * n;
     end
   end
end
```

Then I called the function by passing a parameter as follows in the command prompt:

```
a = BasicClass(pi/3);
```

When I press enter at this step, I am getting an error stating that the call has too many input parameters.

**I am using MATLAB R2007b version.(Please note that this works in versions above R2007b).**

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question mentioned in the link uses R2014a version, which support this feature. **However, I am using R2007b version. The support was added to the MATLAB compiler on versions following R2007b.**

Comment: Your code does not work in more recent Matlab versions, it's simply an error in the documentation. As explained in the other question, the constructor for the class is missing. How is this question related to the MATLAB compiler, I don't fully understand your comment.